# outlook profile .PST and .OST file location using MAPI in delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook-2010, mapi

anyone tell that how to find .PST and .OST file location for particular profile using MAPI in Delphi?

Code:

I have written the below code to find the .PST path. But I am getting the error "2147221233" in the line "HrgetoneProps"

```
 FMapiSession := nil;
  res := MAPILogonEx(0, 'Default Outlook Profile', nil, ulFlags, FMapiSession);
if res = S_OK then
  begin
    res := MAPIAdminProfiles(0, ProfAdmin);
    {$IFDEF DEBUG}CodeSite.Send('MAPIAdminProfiles'); {$ENDIF}
    if res = S_OK then
      begin
        res := FMapiSession.AdminServices(0, ServAdmin);
        if res = S_OK then
          begin
            res := ServAdmin.GetMsgServiceTable(0, Tbl);
            if res = S_OK then
              begin
                res := Tbl.SetColumns(PSPropTagArray(@sptCols), 0);
                if res = S_OK then
                  begin
                    sres.rt := RES_PROPERTY;
                    sres.res.resProperty.relop := RELOP_EQ;
                    sres.res.resProperty.ulPropTag := PR_SERVICE_NAME;
                    sres.res.resProperty.lpProp := @spv;
                    spv.ulPropTag := PR_SERVICE_NAME;
                    spv.Value.lpszA := 'MSUPST MS';
                    res := HrQueryAllRows(Tbl, @sptCols, @sres, nil, 0, pRow);
                    if res = S_OK then
                      begin
                        for I := 0 to pRow.aRow[0].cValues - 1 do
                          begin
                            if (pRow.aRow[0].lpProps[I].ulPropTag = PR_SERVICE_UID) then
                              begin
                                MsgStoreUID := PMAPIUID(pRow.aRow[0].lpProps[I].Value.bin.lpb);
                                break;
                              end;
                          end;
                        res := ServAdmin.OpenProfileSection(MsgStoreUID, TGUID(nil^),
                          MAPI_Force_ACCESS or MAPI_MODIFY, ProfSect);

                        if res = S_OK then
                          begin
                            {$IFDEF DEBUG}CodeSite.Send('HrGetOneProp'); {$ENDIF}
                            res := HrGetOneProp(ProfSect, PR_PST_PATH, propVal);
                            if res = S_OK then
                              begin
                                Result := propVal^.Value.lpszA;
                                MAPIFreeBuffer(propVal);
                              end
                          end
                        else
                          begin
                            // ...
                          end;
                        FreePRows(pRow);
                      end;
                  end;
              end;
          end;
      end;
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. parse the store entry id: its format is documented on MSDN - take a look at `PR_STORE_ENTRYID` in OutlookSpy (I am its author).
2. Look at all service providers in the profile (`IMsgServiceAdmin.GetMsgServiceTable`). For the services with `PR_SERVICE_NAME` == 'MSPST MS' / 'MSUPST MS'/ 'INTERSTOR', etc., read the table of the service providers (`IMsgServiceAdmin.AdminProviders`), open profile section, read `PR_ENTRYID`. Use `IMAPISession::CompareEntryIDs` to compare that entry id with the entry id of the store in question. If they match, read `PR_PST_PATH` property. You can play with this in OutlookSpy - click IMAPISession | AdminServices.
3. Use Redemption (I am also its author) - it exposes `RDOPstStore.PstPath` and `RDOExchangeStore.OstPath`.

Comment: i tried with second option. but it is still not able to get the PR_PST_PATH.can you please share the code snippet in delphi?

Comment: I cannot share my existing code (it is a part of a commercial project). Post your existing code and I will take a look.

Comment: The error is MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND, which mean the property does not exist. The PST path is in the profile section of that service's provider. Call IMsgServiceAdmin.AdminProviders to get IProviderAdmin. Then call IProviderAdmin.GetProviderTable. PST provider will have just one row in that table. Read PR_PROVIDER_UID form that table, use it to call IProviderAdmin.OpenProfileSection, then read the PR_PST_PATH property.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I can retrieve the PR_PST_PATH property. But if the same profile has more than one .PST path,it retrieves the first path.i am not able to retrieve all the .PST path.

Comment: Your code above only works with the first row returned by HrQueryAllRows (pRow.aRow[0]). You need to loop through all of them.